# React Native FormData info is wrapped into "_parts"

Tags: react-native, multipartform-data, form-data

Im a new one in a react native and ran into a problem that FormData behaves itself differently than expected.
My code:

```
let fileToSend = new FormData();
    fileToSend.append('File', {
    name: 'file.name',
    size: 'file.size',
    type: 'file.type',
    uri: 'file://',
});
```

I expected to get something like this:

```
fileToSend = {File: [
   name: 'file.name',
   size: 'file.size',
   type: 'file.type',
   uri: 'file://',
]}
```

But actually Im getting this :

```
fileToSend = [_parts: [
   0: [
     0: 'File',
     1: {
       name: 'file.name',
       size: 'file.size',
       type: 'file.type',
       uri: 'file://',
        }
]]]
```

That makes impossible for me to send a file to server.
Will be very glad for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a year and a bit too late, but make sure that you're sending the body as is and it's not being `JSON.stringify()`'d.

This is what was happening to me so now in our request handler we check to see if the header `Content-Type'` === `'multipart/form-data'`. If it is, we don't stringify the body first.